# How to add edit and delete response menu to Google Form for users through Google API /Form Scripts?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-docs, google-sheets-api, google-forms

Is it possible to add menu to Google Form for users through Google API /Form Scripts to edit and/or delete their own responses. Such menu is available for owner of Google Form.

Comment: No``````````​``````````

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible for now to modify the Form interface for respondent with API.

It is a long requested feature for example changing answer of a question depending previous answer but for now interface modification is not possible.

Stéphane